# mips gdb not loading shared lib info automatically

Tags: gdb, mips, backtrace

I have seen `gdb` reading and loading symbols automatically. (like the below code reading from `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`)

```
----------

gdb 86exec 86core
...
Reading symbols from 86exec...done.

Illegal process-id: 86core.

[New Thread 14983]

[New Thread 14978]

[New Thread 14980]

[New Thread 14981]

[New Thread 14982]
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Core was generated by `./86exec'.

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.


----------
```

**But in my `mips` platform I am not getting that automatic reading done.**

```
---------


Reading symbols from /mipsexec...done.

[New LWP 1333]

[New LWP 1328]

[New LWP 1330]

[New LWP 1331]

[New LWP 1332]

Core was generated by `./mipsexec'.

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.


----------
```

I wanted to know, from where does this information come.

If it is from core file, how can I analyze whether my `mipscore` is having the specific info.

Comment: Are your MIPS libraries built with debugging info? Are you remote debugging with gdbserver, or are you running gdb on the MIPS machine?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that mips gdb doesn't support PIE well. As I know, in PIC, mips use `rld_map` but not `DE_DEBUG` for dynamic information but in PIE mode, mips likes other architectures, using `DT_DEBUG`.

In dynamic linker, there are statements like this:

```
#if !defined __mips__
        /* we disable for mips because normally this page is readonly
         * and modifying the value here needlessly dirties a page.
         * see this post for more info:
         * http://uclibc.org/lists/uclibc/2006-April/015224.html */
        if (dpnt->d_tag == DT_DEBUG)
            dpnt->d_un.d_val = (unsigned long)debug_addr;
#endif
```

this statement in PIC is ok, but not work in PIE. If you remove this `#ifdef`, you will get a segment fault because `.dynamic` section in mips is readonly. `.dynamic` section in arm and x86 etc is writeable.

if you change `.dynamic` section of mips to writeable, and open `DT_DEBUG` handling in dynamic linker, it works, but still has some problems. For example, the readonly VMA is writeable, and need more page copy when fork a subprocess.

I suffered the problem weeks ago and I don't know whether mips gdb works well in Android 4.2 or not. In Android 4.2, all c/c++ files are built with PIE.